# Ignore spaces and dashes and capture only digits of specific length

Tags: regex

I have a scenario wherein I have a string which contains a series of numbers, spaces or dashes. I want to capture the groups of numbers having length between 14 to 16 only.  I tried with various combinations like below,

```
 1. [0-9](?:[- ]?){14,16}
 2. [0-9]([- ]?){14,16}
 3. [0-9]{15,16}|[0-9]{4}.?[0-9]{4}.?[0-9]{4}.?[0-9]{3,4}|[0-9]{4}([\\ \\-]?)[0-9]{4}\1[0-9]{4}[ ]?[-]?[ ]?[0-9]{3,4}|[0-9]{14}|[0-9]{4}([\\ ?|\\-?]?)[0-9]{4}\1[0-9]{4}\1[0-9]{4}
```

My input string is "My data contains string `34567892345567` or `3456789234556734` or `345678923455634` and `34 5678  92345-567` or `34--567   8923---4556-734` or `34567-8923 455634`"

The only constant is length of subsequent digits as 14, 15 or 16. My output should capture following groups,

```
 1. 34567892345567
 2. 3456789234556734
 3. 345678923455634
 4. 34 5678  92345-567
 5. 34--567   8923---4556-734
 6. 34567-8923 455634
```

Please suggest a regex to capture above groups.

Answer (score 1):

You were dancing around it.

```
([0-9][- ]*){14,16}
```

Explanation:

`(__________){14,16}` 14 to 16 occurrences of ...
`_[0-9]_____________` a digit, followed by ...
`______[- ]*________` 0 or more hyphens or spaces

Note: this will include spaces and hyphens at the end, but not at the beginning.  To include spaces and hyphens at the start, use:

```
[- ]*([0-9][- ]*){14,16}
```

To exclude spaces and hyphens at the end, use:

```
([0-9][- ]*){13,15}[0-9]
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I would go for regex to exclude spaces and hyphens at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following pattern:

```
(\d[ -]*?){14,16}
```

Make sure to include the `?` in the pattern to make it non-greedy. That way your capture group won't include a trailing space.

https://regex101.com/r/JMNErk/1